# Chef recipe resource how to run recipe/resource only after completing oracle setup.exe is run completely

Tags: oracle, installation, chef-infra, oracle12c, chef-recipe

I am writing a chef recipe to install Oracle EE software (by running setup.exe in silent mode) using chef resource 'execute' as below.

---

```
str_command = "<dir>/setup.exe -silent -nowait -noconfig  -waitforcompletion ORACLE_HOME=... ORACLE_BASE=... " # other parameters for silent installation

Chef::Log.info("-before-")
execute 'install_oracle_ee' do
    command str_command
    live_stream true
    timeout "#{node['mycookbk']['timeout']['num']}"
    not_if {File.exists?("#{node['mycookbk']['oracle']['oracle_home']}/bin")}
end
Chef::Log.info("-after-")
```

---

**After the software is installed successfully** I need to execute resources / recipe which will 'create a db instance' and then 'create the database'.

---

**At the moment the execute resource exists after running the command and directly moves to the next resource / recipe in the run list.**

But I need to make sure the set up is completed before doing that. Can anyone please suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means the command is not actually waiting for completion. Chef does wait for the provided executable to finish (in fact it has to, there is no option to not do that). Double check your CLI options for the installer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Chef actually doesnt. It will print simply -before- and -after- and then proceed to next resources/ recipes. It doesnt wait until the command (setup execution) is completed. 
It is kind of running in background so chef has no idea on what is happening.

Comment: That's not related, you're confusing compile time and converge time. Those logging statements run at compile time, before _any_ resources (other than those specifically hacked to run at compile time).

Comment: This is the first time I am using chef. It is strange that it executes the log statements during compile time. So if a setup.exe is being triggered during a 'execute' resource execution, will the next resource's command wait until previous one is completed ?

Comment: It runs all code at the base level of the recipe at compile time. See https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for details.